# Offline file syncing causes permission issues and hides some (but not all) desktop shortcuts

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions, shortcuts, offline-files, sync-center

I have a user running Windows 10 on his laptop who I have enabled Offline Files in Control Panels' Sync Center. Initially everything appeared to be working fine after we restarted his computer, but the next day he said that a number of his shortcuts on the desktop had disappeared, and when he tried to open the shortcuts that were still on his desktop, he received the error message "Windows cannot access [filepath]. Contact your network administrator to request access.

I attempted to look at the permission settings in the property windows of the shortcut but the security tab simply displayed "You do not have permission to view or edit this object's permission settings."

Disabling Offline Files again returned his desktop to the previous state with all of his shortcuts, and he regained access to the files the shortcuts link to.

The offline files are not currently encrypted.

Any ideas how I can leave Offline Files enabled without causing the behavior described above?

Comment: I checked Bing 'Offline Files permissions' https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/offline-files-access-is-denied/b1adc231-a4c2-4a5b-80b8-93269851febf

Comment: Thanks for your response @vssher, but I did come across that post in my own research- the solution offered there is disabling file encryption and as I mentioned above encryption isn't currently enabled.

Comment: Have you tried, in folder options, show hidden files folders and drives?